# VTK retrieve a specific actor from a renderer

Tags: python, 3d, vtk

I have the following code:

```
my_renderer = vtkRenderer()
my_actor = vtkActor()

my_renderer.AddActor(my_actor)
```

Is there a way to recover a specific actor from the renderer? VtkRenderer has the following function `GetActors()` which returns a collection of actors but I cannot see how to identify any specific one, if say I only wanted to change the property of one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you specific the wanted actor?

One possible solution is: implement a selfActor which inherits from `vtkActor`. Then, record a name in `selfActor`. Then, you can use `actor->GetName()` to obtain the name. You can identify the actor by the name.